# Ahead-of-time compilation is only work for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Recently I'm facing a problem of page loading. So I want something like AOT compilation for accelerating JavaScript executing speed. But I haven't seen anything like this. Is it Angular AOT compilation compatible for modern browser js runtime? Or it just only work for Angular?

Comment: Angular is a Js framework at the end it just compiles js in AOT, you can use native js in Angular also, but is generally recommened to do it Angular way

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks your comment. After AOT, Angular's output file is still a js file? It still need JIT to run it. Right?

Comment: You are confused between JIT and AOT please read the documentation check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450226/angular-2-just-in-time-jit-vs-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation

Comment: I understand what they mean. I think I confused the scope of capable. AOT is only use for Angular to compile html syntax to JavaScript. JIT is used for running JavaScript. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AOT availability depends on your framework. You can do it for example with Angular (the v2) but not AngularJS (the v1).

And you can't do it for vanilla JS.

Comment: Why Angular's document compare it with JIT. At last it still need JIT to execute.

Comment: JIT (Just In Time) means that the compilation is done automatically in the browser at runtime. You don't anything in particular (except a browser) for _JIT to execute_

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. AOT is only used for Angular compilation.