# What is the difference between Pre-JIT & AOT compiler (C#)?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, jit, aot

I have gone through some articles on internet which tells the difference between JIT & AOT compilers

but did not found any article telling difference between Pre-JIT & AOT compiler (C#).
Can someone please help me with this?

[Good to read](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/jit-just-in-time-compiler/)

[Telerik blog](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation)

*Thanks*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Just-in-Time (JiT) vs Ahead-of-Time (AoT) compilation in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450226/just-in-time-jit-vs-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-in-angular)

Comment: pre-jit appears to be an old term related to ngen.exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator, a tool for end users to compile an assembly to native code. In other words `[build] => [install] => [jit & execute]` becomes `[build] => [install] => [pre-jit] => [execute]`

Comment: When you say AOT do you refer .NET 7's Native AOT ?

Comment: @styx No.. actually my question is regarding Pre-JIT & AOT.
In some articles I found that JIT are of 3 types (Pre, Normal, Econo). 
Out of these, I am looking for difference in Pre-JIT & AOT.

[Pre-JIT: Compiles complete source code in single compilation cycle]